# Консоль Windows при запуске main.exe моментально закрывается

Tags: c++, консоль, codeblocks, main

Я использую Code::Blocks, console application.

Comment: Ну программа заканчивается, консоль закрывается, никаких неожиданностей.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    //код
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы выяснить в чём проблема. Раньше не использовал system pause. И, кстати, случилось всё после удаления пакета visual studio.

Comment: @slime-shock, выше же был ответ. Программа заканчивает работу, консоль закрывается. Либо предварительно запустить cmd.exe и оттуда вручную запускать приложение, или добавить в программу либо паузу, либо запрос на ввод от пользователя. VS для ленивых оставляет консоль живой

Answer (score 2):

Нужно написать `system("pause");`